# fuel consumption in CR-V 2007

Tags: honda, fuel-consumption, crv

lately I found my car consuming more fuel than usual,it was doing 8 liters per 100km,then it raised to 12 liters per 100km,I asked its agency to check for the problem,they found nothing unusual,after a while it decreased as normal for few days then back for hi consumption I don't know what is going on?any help?

Comment: Has anything changed, like where you purchase fuel from? Where do you live? How many miles are on the vehicle? Has any tuneup work been done? This question is nearly impossible to answer because it is way too broad. There needs to be a ton more information to even start helping you.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I imagine the agency reset the [fuel trims](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/24149/675), which is why you experienced normal fuel consumption for a few days. Could you [hook up a scan tool](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1470/675) and read the fuel trims and any DTC's that might be present?