# Is this PCV hose broken?

Tags: toyota, corolla, air-intake, pcv-valve

I asked a question earlier about a P0171 MIL in my 2007 toyota corolla. The question is here:
[Diagnosing P0171 2007 Toyota Corolla](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25478/diagnosing-p0171-2007-toyota-corolla)
I only have a OBD2 reader, I just bought a scanner, which should come on Monday but when I was looking around my engine for leaks and such, I saw a little crack where the PCV pipe connects with the air intake pipe. I've attached a picture with the crack outlined in red. I want to know if that is normal or if it's significant enough to cause the P0171 error.

[image]

I know this is a response to my earlier post but I'm not quite sure how to ask a question from my original question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It certainly looks cracked.  You could try spraying some EGR cleaner at the crack while the engine is idling. If the EGR cleaner gets sucked in through the cracked pipe, the revs of the engine will change, which will confirm you have an air leak.

Comment: Carb cleaner, throttle body cleaner, or brake cleaner would also do here